# How do I get the width of a Form in Elm?

Tags: elm

I'm trying to write a function that takes an Form and arranges three copies of it into a triangle-like formation. As an example, doing this to a green triangle would yield the Triforce. I have decided that using collage was the best way to do this. I'm having trouble adjusting the size of the collage according to the size of the Form. It should be both twice as wide and twice as high as the Form.

Comment: How are you creating the Forms?  I don't think there is a simple way to get the width from the Form itself because Forms are based on a variety of underlying objects, e.g. Element, Text, Shape, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could come up with is to keep track of the width of the shapes you are using to create the Forms.  One way to do that could be to create a record type to hold each Form, with its width:

```
type alias MyForm =
  {   form : Form
    , width : Int
  }

makeCircleForm: Float -> MyForm
makeCircleForm  r = {form: (filled grey (circle r)), width: (round 2*r)}
```

That will make it more of a hassle to work with your Forms, but at least you will have the width.

Comment: Thank you. I thought there might be a more elegant way, but this will do. There should be a package for simple shapes that are elements, I think.